# Make siren with UM3561 louder

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have a UM3561.  With the circuit below I could achieve  95dB sound.

I would like to increase sound level to 100dB.

What changes must be made to the UM3561 circuit to meet the sound level requirement?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmvci2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have made changes in the circuit. I have limited current here.  If I use a 3.3V regulator I could achieve less dB level.  As I understand the higher the voltage the higher the volume.
Yes it's true if I use a 4ohm speaker I could achieve more sound.

Comment: Use an amplifier on the output.

Comment: 1.  You should still power the **speaker** from the higher voltage supply.  2.  Q1 and Q2 are a mess.  I don't know what you were trying to do there, but I do think you got it wrong.  3.  The UM3561 needs **3.3V** not 5V.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything else, you need to correct the error in the circuit that will destroy your UM3561.

The [UM3561](http://www.e-ele.net/DataSheet/UM3561.pdf) is intended to operate on 3.3V.

The circuit you reference has the UM3561 powered with 9V.  If you built it as shown, then you can expect the chip to die in short order.

Connect Vdd (pin 5 of the UM3561) to the junction of R3 and the zener diode.  That will provide 3.3V to the chip instead of 9V.  That's not an efficient way to do it, but it's more efficient than burning out chips.  You'll also need to connect the junction of S3 and S2 to the 3.3V source rather than the 9V.

With that out of the way, you have a few options to make the siren louder:

1. Use a better speaker.  Two speakers rated for the same impedance and power can have different efficiencies.  The more efficient one will be louder for the same power.
2. Use a speaker with lower impedance.  A 4 ohm speaker will consume more power for the same voltage than an 8 ohm speaker.  The 4 ohm speaker will (usually) be louder.
3. Use a smaller value resistor for R2.  More current through the base of Q1 means more current through the collector of Q1.  That means more current through the speaker, so it will be louder.
4. Higher supply voltage.  If you used 12V instead of 9V, then you'd have more current through the speaker and it would be louder.
5. Use a transistor with higher gain for Q1.  That will allow more current through the collector for the same base current.
6. Use something besides a 9V transistor battery for power.  The chances are very good that the battery voltage drops while the siren is sounding.

---

What I'd do:

1. Use 2 alkaline (or carbon zinc) 1.5V batteries in series for power.  C or D cells.
2. Get rid of R3 and the zener diode and power the UM3561 from the batteries directly.
3. Use a lower value resistor for R2.
4. Use a "beefier" transistor for Q1.  The BC547 is only rated for 100mA of collector current.  Use something that can handle at least a few hundred milliamperes.
5. Use a 4 ohm speaker instead of an 8 ohm speaker.

Points 1 and 2 save you the wasted energy in the zener "regulator" and provides you with a power source that can provide more current to the speaker.

The rest of the points let you get more current through the speaker despite the lower supply voltage.

Point 4 is needed because the BC547 would probably burn out if forced to deliver the needed current.

---

Here's the circuit implemented as I suggested:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9aH7b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The BC548C has higher current gain than the transistor you were using.  I'm pretty sure it'll withstand the power dissipation.

R2 is lower so that you get more current through the base of the transistor, and the higher gain of the BC548C means you'll get more current through the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Do not build the circuit as per that "application note" that you linked. If you do you will likely fry the chip. According to the [data sheet](http://www.e-ele.net/DataSheet/UM3561.pdf) I found the part is designed to operate at 3V not 9V as shown at your link. Many things you will find on the web are suspect.

[image]

Figure out the proper power source for your chip (hint why is the zener voltage not connected to anything) and then consider using a higher voltage to drive the speaker with the NPN transistor to get out more volume.